# Commutator length of the center $Z(D')$ of $D'$ in a division ring $D$

Tags: division-algebras, division-rings

Let $D$ be a division ring, and $D^\times$ the multiplicative group of $D$. Denoted $D'$ (resp. $Z(D')$) by the derived subgroup of $D^\times$ (resp. the center of $D'$). Here, we consider $D'$ infinite and $Z(D')$ finite. Put $g\in Z(D')$. How many commutators can $g$ be written in $D'$? We also only know that $Z(D')$ is a cyclic group.